# codeigniter active record or general mysql help

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am query a database to get all the employers names out of my database, but I only want to get the ones where their ID is present in my jobs table, here is what I am trying to do.

```
$this->db->select('*')
    ->from('employers')
->join('jobwall', 'jobwall.employers_employer_id = employers.employer_id', 'left');
```

However this does not return the correct results, how can I select all my employers from the employers table but only if they have data in the jobwall table?

Comment: what do you get as result? do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a WHERE clause:

```
$sql = '
    SELECT *
    FROM employers
    LEFT JOIN jobwall ON jobwall.employers_employer_id = employers.employer_id
    WHERE employers.employer_id
    IN (SELECT employers_employer_id FROM jobwall)
';

$this->db->query($sql);
```

I'm not sure how complicated this would be to create using Codeigniter's activerecord class.

Comment: This does not work the second arugment is being passed a string, I need it to be passed as ``employers`.`employers_id`` it is currently getting passed as 'employer.employer_id' so it is looking for ID's that match that string not the value of the row

Comment: Thanks I look forward to finally having an answer for this been bugging me for hours

Answer (score 0):

I think a better WHERE clause might be:

```
SELECT *
FROM employers
LEFT JOIN jobwall ON jobwall.employers_employer_id = employers.employer_id
WHERE jobwall.id IS NOT NULL
```

This will exclude any rows that don't have a corresponding job.

You should use whatever Primary Key your `jobwall` table has if `jobwall.id` doesn't exist.

This can also be written using ActiveRecord easily.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand you exactly, but I think you should use `join` without `left`:

```
this->db->select('*')->from('employers')->join('jobwall', 'jobwall.employers_employer_id = employers.employer_id');
```